# DataGridView event for checked change

Tags: c#, winforms, events, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` which has a bunch of columns plus a checkBoxColumn called **IsChecked**.

I want to raise an event whenever a row's checked state changes. Checking or Unchecking a row may be done either when user clicks the checkBox or when they press *space* key on a row.

this is how I added checkBoxColumn to my grid:

```
dgvMain.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn { 
            Name = "IsChecked" , 
            Width = 20, 
            Visible = false,
            HeaderText = "",
            SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable,
            DisplayIndex = Columns.Count, //to be displayed as last column
            ValueType = typeof(bool),
            FalseValue = false,
            TrueValue = true
        });
```

and this is how I check the cell when space key is pressed:

```
private void dgvMain_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
     foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvMain.SelectedRows)
     {
         bool? checkState = (bool?)row.Cells["IsChecked"].Value;
         if (checkState == null || checkState == false)
             checkState = true;
         else
             checkState = false;
         row.Cells["IsChecked"].Value = checkState;
     }

}
```

Attempt # 1:
I tried using `CellEndEdit` event which only helped when you check the cell using mouse, but when I press space and the cell checks/unchecks `CellEndEdit` does not fire.

Attempt # 2:
I tried using `CellValueChanged` event, which works fine when I press space, and also **when I check the box using mouse and leave the row** but when I check and uncheck the box multiple times, nothing happens. It seems like `CellValueChanged` raises when the cell is finished editing by mouse.

Attempt # 3:
I Also tried using `CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged` which responds to first checked change caused by mouse but does not respond to rapid checked changes bu mouse, only the first one and also when you leave the row. **I want to catch all checked changes, even if user changes the checked state rapidly by clicking on the checkBox, that counts too.**

I'm not sure if there is any event already for this purpose or not. If not, how can I add an eventHandler for this column programmatically?

Comment: If your grid is bound to a `DataTable` (or `DataSet`), then put the event on its `ColumnChanged` or `ColumnChanging` event.

Comment: If your grid is **not** `DataBound`, when you create the cell, add a handler to it.

Comment: @user959631 how can I add a handler to the cell when creating it?

Comment: Please see Mohamed Salemyan's answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the `CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged` event handler, trigger `EndEdit` so that the value changed event is triggered.

```
void dataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.IsCurrentCellDirty && dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == CheckColumnIndex)
    {
        dataGridView1.EndEdit();
    }
}
```

In the `CellValueChanged` event handler get the value from the CheckBoxColumn.

```
void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == CheckColumnIndex)
    {
        DataGridViewCheckBoxCell checkCell = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
        bool achecked = Convert.ToBoolean(checkCell.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don worry man I just had to check a couple of things ;) enjoy it

Answer (score 2):

you can use CellValueChanged event for getting checkbox value:

```
private void dgvMain_CellValueChanged(object sender, 
                                          DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvMain.Rows) 
    {
       if (row.Cells["RowWithCheckBox"].Value != null &&(bool)row.Cells["RowWithCheckBox"].Value)
       {
          //do something
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mohamed, just one little problem, using this solution if I click on a row's checkbox cell multiple times (rapid check and uncheck) the event does not fires for any of them but only when I leave the row (so that cell ends being edited).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `CellValidating` and `CellValueChanged` events if it suits you.