# DataTable.GetChanges() returns null

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, datagridview

I have a DataGridView that has a DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn. I'm trying to get the DataSource to update so that I can retrieve a DataTable of changes to save to the database. I've read over several articles here and on other sites but I have had no success yet. I found that the CurrentCellDirtyStateChange event must execute after the CellContentClick event to avoid having to physically move off the DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn Cell to get the underlying datasource to get the changes. I am successful in retrieving .GetChanges() if I move off the cell. The problem is that the CurrentCellDirtyStateChange never fires. What did I miss? The correct handlers are defined in the .designer.cs file.

```
private void saveChangesToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = fileData.GetChanges();
    if (dt == null) { return; }

    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        if (row.Field<int>("Id") != null)
        {
            if (row.Field<bool>("Selected"))
            {
                // update
            }
            else
            {
                // delete
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // add 
        }
    }

    fileData.AcceptChanges();
    dgvColumnValues.ResetBindings();
}


private void dgvColumnValues_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex != dgvColumnValues.Columns["Selected"].Index) return;

    dgvColumnValues.BeginEdit(true);
    dgvColumnValues.CurrentCell.Value = !(bool) dgvColumnValues.CurrentCell.Value;
    dgvColumnValues.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(true);
    dgvColumnValues.EndEdit();
    bsAcceptableColumn.EndEdit();

}

private void dgvColumnValues_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dgvColumnValues.IsCurrentCellDirty)
    {
        dgvColumnValues.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
    }
}
```

UPDATE:
Even just bypassing the IsCurrentCellDirty check and calling `dgvColumnValues.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);` the .GetChanges() still returns null.

UPDATE:
I figured out how to invoke the CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged event handler by calling `dgvColumnValues.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(true);` all code is executed in the event handler properly but the .GetChanges() is still null when I click save without changing cell focus. My understanding was that the CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged event handler was the fix for that. Now I'm really stumped. Code sample update to reflect the new changes.

Comment: See whether my answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22284280/datagridview-event-for-checked-change helps.

Comment: That didn't help. All it did was move the .EndEdit() of the datagridview that I was already using in the CellContentClick event handler into the CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged event handler. The .GetChanges() was still null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, Solution found. I came across a great little helper method [here](http://geek-goddess-bonnie.blogspot.com/2009/09/fun-with-datasets.html). The blog post gives a little insite into what happens. The method was written for a DataSet but I modified it to a DataTable to suit my needs. So the full working code is as follows...

```
private void saveChangesToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CommitProposedChanges((DataTable)dgvColumnValues.DataSource);
    DataTable dt = ((DataTable)dgvColumnValues.DataSource).GetChanges();
    if (dt == null) { return; }

    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        if (row.Field<int>("Id") != null)
        {
            if (row.Field<bool>("Selected"))
            {
                // update
            }
            else
            {
                // delete
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // add this row to the table
        }
    }

    ((DataTable)dgvColumnValues.DataSource).AcceptChanges();
    dgvColumnValues.ResetBindings();
}

private void dgvColumnValues_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex != dgvColumnValues.Columns["Selected"].Index) return;
    DataGridViewCheckBoxCell cell = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)((DataGridView)sender).Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
    if (cell.ValueType != typeof(bool)) return;
    cell.Value = !(bool)cell.Value;

    dgvColumnValues.EndEdit();
}

protected virtual void CommitProposedChanges(DataTable dt)
{
    if (dt == null) return;

    for (int nRow = 0; nRow < dt.Rows.Count; nRow++)
    {
        if (dt.Rows[nRow].HasVersion(DataRowVersion.Proposed))
        {
            dt.Rows[nRow].EndEdit();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm still baffled as to why the original code didn't work. Other posters with the same type of question seemed to have success with it. If anyone can explain it to me that would be great.