# Datatable.GetChanges() always returns null

Tags: c#, linq, dataset, strongly-typed-dataset

What I'm trying to do is edit the matching row and change a value for a column but it keeps returning null. I believe this is because of the way that I save the query to an object because if I access the query directly then it keeps processing the query everytime. What is the best way to handle this?

```
using (SymbolsTableAdapter symbolAdapter = new SymbolsTableAdapter())
using (Dataset.SymbolsDataTable symbolTable = new Dataset.SymbolsDataTable())
{
    symbolAdapter.Fill(symbolTable);

    foreach (var error in errors)
    {
        var query = from c in symbolTable
                    where c.Symbol == error.Key && c.Market == error.Value
                    select c;

        Dataset.SymbolsRow row = query.AsParallel().FirstOrDefault();

        if (row != null)
        {
            row.isUnderReview = true;
        }
    }

    // now save
    if (symbolTable.GetChanges() != null)
    {
        symbolTable.AcceptChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is errors in your code ? Does it go inside loop ?

Comment: @dotnetstep It never receives any errors but it doesn't ever hit the line that says symbolTable.AcceptChanges();

Comment: As it never go inside loop so your table does not change after it get load so no changes will found so not able to hit the accept changes.

Comment: @dotnetstep I do need to mention that it does go inside the loop and it does hit the line where it changes the value in the row

Comment: Try Dataset.SymbolsRow row = query.FirstOrDefault(); instead of your AsParallel

Comment: @dotnetstep I changed it to that and there is no difference at all

Comment: @dotnetstep It does hit the accept changes line but it doesn't give me any errors and it doesn't actually seem to change anything

Comment: Then What is issue ? You said that Getchanges is always null and if it is null then it will never go inside condition to execute AcceptChanges. If you do call Getchanges after acceptchanges then it will return null or blank.

Comment: possible duplicate of [DataTable.GetChanges() returns null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25064227/datatable-getchanges-returns-null)

Comment: The problem after doing your changes is now that it is hitting the line for acceptchanges, it doesn't actually change anything. The isUnderReview isn't changed on the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I'm not sure why AcceptChanges wasn't actually doing anything but I changed my code a bit to the below and it works just fine for anyone's future reference

```
Dataset.SymbolsDataTable tempSymbolsTable = new Dataset.SymbolsDataTable();
tempSymbolsTable = (Dataset.SymbolsDataTable)symbolTable.GetChanges();

                if (tempSymbolsTable != null)
                {
                    symbolAdapter.Update(tempSymbolsTable);
                    tempSymbolsTable.Dispose();
                }
```